# Best practise for two libraries sharing codebase

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Assume there are two libraries

```
shared-features-core.lib
shared-features-full.lib
```

In terms of features, assume that `shared-features-full.lib` is a superset of `shared-features-core.lib`.

What is the best practise to have all code in `shared-features-core.lib` included in `shared-features-full.lib` at all times? Ideally without having to manage copies of the code.

Comment: [Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) are the way to go here.

Comment: What is `lib`? Do you mean dll? Is it a problem to have 2 dlls (full simply includes core as reference) or what?

Comment: @Sinatr in this case it is a dll. it is not a problem but in this particular case the result would be 3 libraries with one library consisting of only 2 classes. conceptionally it would work with git-submodules as suggested by Thierry Prost, but I wonder if there was a more manageable way having all code consolidated in just one library

Comment: You can use shared projects to share source between different projects/solutions.

Comment: Within your solution you have two projects core and full. Within the core project all files are normally added as usual. Within the full project all the same files are *added as link* and additionally contains the other files as normal files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these two libs are in the same solution, I recommend to `full` will use the `core` as project reference.

If not, the `core` should be a nuget, and `full` will use it as package reference.